# Suppose that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ to a group of order $24$. Determine the possible homomorphic images

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Suppose that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ to a group of order $24$. Determine the possible homomorphic images

I'm trying to solve this exercise from Gallian's book, and I'm stuck here.

I know by the First Isomorphisms Theorem that $|\varphi(\mathbb{Z}_{36})|\Bigl ||\mathbb{Z}_{36}|$

And by Lagrange's Theorem that $|\varphi(\mathbb{Z}_{36})|\Bigl | 24$

So the possible orders of $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}_{36})$ are $1,2,3,4,6$ or $12$.

Please give me some tips of what should I do next to determine the possibilities of $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}_{36}).$

Comment: Note that the image of a cyclic group under some group homomorphism will again be cyclic.

Comment: Why $|\varphi(\mathbb Z/36\mathbb Z)|$ cannot be $4$?

Comment: Now consider $\varphi : \Bbb{Z}_{36} \to G$ with $G = \Bbb{Z}_2 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{12}, \Bbb{Z}_{3} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{8}, \Bbb{Z}_4 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_6, \Bbb{Z}_6 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_4, \Bbb{Z}_{12}\oplus \Bbb{Z}_2$ given as $\varphi(1)=(1,0)$.